# Take a 4-digit input and automatically the computer press Enter

Tags: gcc

I want that as soon as the user inputs a 4-digit number computer press enter (meaning only 4 digit input will be taken and as soon it will be taken the program will continue itself. User has no need to press enter key).
The program is written in C. I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: you would be taking away the ability to 'verify' no fat fingered mistakes

Answer (score 0):

The *getchar()* function will gets a character without the need to press enter.

You can use a *for* loop to call the *getchar()* function as many times as you need it. As the loop runs, each character will be inserted in the number array.

```
char number[4];
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    number[i] = getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

We can then use the *sscanf()* function to convert the *char* array to an int!

```
int num;
sscanf(number, "%d", &num);
```